# Timeout when executing long running procedure with Hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, stored-procedures, jdbc

The scenario is this, i have one procedure that takes +- 10 minutes to run, this procedure do a lot of things on the Sql Server Database, insert, delete, update... When i run on the database i don't have any problem, but when i run it using the Hibernate or JDBC it gives Timeout error after 2 hours of execution. I have already altered the procedure to do nothing or less things so the execution could be faster, and i didn't got the timeout error.

to execute i'm using the 
`List l = session.getNamedQuery("Proc_Name").list()`
the procedure returns all the "log" from the execution.

Thanks =D

Comment: If you have a sql procedure that takes more than 2 hours to run the problem has nothing to do with how you are calling it, it has everything to do with the inefficient procedure. The way to fix this issue is to fix the procedure, not prevent your connection from timing out.

Comment: Let's say that this stored procedure really *does* need to do two hours of work - and you have certainly not convinced anyone that it does - why does Java need to wait for it to complete? Have you considered using a job, Java could start the job, return immediately, and go on with its business? What user is sitting there staring at the screen, waiting 2 hours for that procedure to finish?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the attention. The Procedure takes 10 minutes to run, the java process really start it, but it like it "loose" the connection and the java process don't get the resultSet. so after 2 hours it gives the Timeout error.